# How to access a file through LAN/IP address (not shared) using NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, ssh, openssh

I'd like to know if there's a way on how to access local area network file (not shared)
(i.e, 192.168.1.132/folder/foo.txt)? without Username/Password.

I'm thinking about ***ssh*** modules but I don't know where to start. Maybe can you suggest?

Comment: What operating system? I would start by checking if the port you expose the server on is accessible from the outside (you might want to check your firewall).

Comment: @mingos: It's Win 10. I've tried different way to access the file using bash sftp (with public keys) and put the file on the server and it works. But, now the use case is to listen on the file from the network directory if file has changed. (I'm afraid I do not have access to change the firewall)